# Issue when using Jersey 2.x with IBM WAS 8.x to scan and register JAX-RS resources

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0, websphere-8

I am trying to integrate Jersey 2.22.1 with IBM WAS 8.5.4.I have a couple of JAX-RS resources under a certain package (com.innovation.postdata.integration.rest.test.jersey.resources).One of the JAX-RS resource is shown below:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/service")
public class FileSubmissionTestRestService
{
    @PUT
    @Consumes({ "text/csv" })
    @Path("/file")
    public Response submitBordereaux (@QueryParam("forceResponse") String forceResponse)
    {

        if (forceResponse != null && !"".equals (forceResponse))
        {
            switch (forceResponse)
            {
                case "404":
                    return Response.status (Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity ("Resource Not Found!").build ();
                case "401":
                    return Response.status (Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity ("Unauthorized user!").build ();
                case "403":
                    return Response.status (Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).entity ("User not allowed!").build ();
                case "405":
                    return Response.status (Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED).entity ("Unsupported HTTP method!").build ();
                case "415":
                    return Response.status (Response.Status.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE)
                            .entity ("Media type not supported.It should be TEXT/CSV or APPLICATION/JSON!").build ();
                case "500":
                    return Response.status (Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity ("Error occured on server!").build ();
                default:
                    return Response.status (Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build ();
            }
        }

        return Response.status (Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity ("Error occured on server!").build ();

    }

}
```

and I added a entry in web.xml as shown below

```
       <servlet>
              <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name>
              <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
              <init-param>
                     <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>                
                     <param-value>com.innovation.postdata.integration.rest.test.jersey.resources</param-value>
              </init-param>
              <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>
       <servlet-mapping>
              <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name>
              <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
```

I also added a custom run time property(**com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRSEngine**) and set it to **true** in WAS to disable default WAS JAX-RS implementation.The JAX-RS resources (under com.innovation.postdata.integration.rest.test.jersey.resources) are packaged in a separate jar that is added to the main EAR WEB-INF/lib when packaging the EAR. When I start WAS I get to see only this in the start up logs:

> [1/5/16 0:27:24:106 GMT-05:00] 00000070 ServletWrappe I
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I:
>   [InnovationInsurer] [/Jasper] [JAX-RS REST Servlet]: Initialization
>   successful.

No where it says that it tried to scan the resource packages or anything like this.Just this.The jars I am using are:

```
hk2-api-2.4.0-b31.jar 
hk2-locator-2.4.0-b31.jar
hk2-utils-2.4.0-b31.jar 
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar 
javax.inject-2.4.0-b31.jar 
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jersey-client-2.22.1.jar 
jersey-common-2.22.1.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar 
jersey-guava-2.22.1.jar 
jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.1.jar 
jersey-server-2.22.1.jar 
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar 
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar 
aopalliance-1.0.jar
```

I am using Postman Rest Client to access the JAX-RS at http://10.2.64.3:9080/Jasper/rest/service/file?forceResponse=403 but I am always getting 200 OK which is wrong.Can anybody please help me out as to what could be the reason for this? Why is not even trying to scan the package and only saying servlet successfully initialized.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is a bug in Websphere that prevent package scanning to work correctly (it works only if the classes are under WEB-INF/classes, not from WEB-INF/lib).

Some informations here: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/169221/packagesresourceconfig.html

I've workarounded that issue using:

```
public class MyRestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
  public MyRestApplication() {
    register(DefaultExceptionMapper.class);
    register(ConstraintViolationExceptionExceptionMapper.class);
    register(JacksonJsonProvider.class); 

    // does not work in IBM WAS 8.5.5 full profile: see it here
    // https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/169221/packagesresourceconfig.html
    // and
    // http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PM99378 
    // packages(getClass().getPackage().getName(), LookupEndpoint.class.getPackage().getName());

    // Works under WAS 8.5
    registerClasses(LookupEndpoint.class, XEndpoint.class, YEndpoint.class);
  }
}
```

and

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey_v2-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>        
      <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>x.y.z.MyRestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

That is obviously not optimal (you must maintain yourself the list of endpoints to be used) but at least it works.